# How to append Line to previous Line?

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have a Log file which need to be parsed and analysed. File contains something similar like below:

#### File:

```
20141101 server contain dump
20141101 server contain nothing
    {uekdmsam ikdas 

jwdjamc ksadkek} ssfjddkc * kdlsdl
sddsfd jfkdfk 
20141101 server contain dump
```

Based on the above scenario, I have to check if the starting line doesn't contain date or Number I have to append to previous line.

#### Output file:

```
20141101 server contain dump
20141101 server contain nothing {uekdmsam ikdas jwdjamc ksadkek} ssfjddkc * kdlsdl sddsfd jfkdfk 
20141101 server contain dump
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A version in `perl`, using negative lookaheads:

```
$ perl -0pe 's/\n(?!([0-9]{8}|$))//g' test.txt
20141101 server contain dump
20141101 server contain nothing    {uekdmsam ikdas jwdjamc ksadkek} ssfjddkc * kdlsdlsddsfd jfkdfk
20141101 server contain dump
```

`-0` allows the regex to be matched across [the entire file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742526/how-to-search-and-replace-across-multiple-lines-with-perl), and `\n(?!([0-9]{8}|$))` is a negative lookahead, meaning a newline not followed by 8 digits, or end of the line (which, with `-0`, will be the end of the file).

Comment: @terdon, updated to save last newline.

Comment: Nice one! I'd upvote you but I'm afraid I already had :)

Comment: No, `-0` if for NUL-delimited records. Use `-0777` to slurp the entire file in memory (which you don't need to here).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas So whats the best way to make Perl match the newline, other than reading the whole file in?

Comment: See the other answers that process the file line by line.

Comment: i think `-00pe` would reduce some complexity.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yes, it should be more efficient, but produces wrong results if non-log lines include blank ones?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas so there's no middle ground between "matching a newline" and "reading the whole file and the library next to it"?

Answer (score 5):

May be a little bit easy with `sed`

```
sed -e ':1 ; N ; $!b1' -e 's/\n\+\( *[^0-9]\)/\1/g'
```

- first part `:1;N;$!b1` collect all lines in file divided by `\n` in 1
  long line
- second part strip newline symbol if it followed non-digit symbol with
  possible spaces between its.

To avoid memory limitation (espesially for big files) you can use:

```
sed -e '1{h;d}' -e '1!{/^[0-9]/!{H;d};/^[0-9]/x;$G}' -e 's/\n\+\( *[^0-9]\)/\1/g'
```

Or forget a difficult `sed`scripts and to remember that year starts from `2`

```
tr '\n2' ' \n' | sed -e '1!s/^/2/' -e 1{/^$/d} -e $a
```

Comment: Nice, +1. Could you add an explanation of how it works please?

Comment: Aw. Nice. I always do `tr '\n' $'\a' | sed $'s/\a\a*\( *[^0-9]\)/\1/g' | tr $'\a' '\n'` myself.

Comment: Sorry, have to downvote though for using things that are not [POSIX BASIC REGULAR EXPRESSION](https://www.mirbsd.org/man7/re_format)S in [sed(1)](https://www.mirbsd.org/man1/sed), which is a GNUism.

Comment: @mirabilos Kindly ask you to indicate non-POSIX exptression in my script.

Comment: There is no `+` or `\+` in POSIX basic regular expressions.

Comment: @mirabilos From `man grep` 

>**Basic vs Extended Regular Expressions**

>       In basic regular expressions the meta-characters ?, +, {, |, (, and )  lose  their  special  meaning;

>       instead use the backslashed versions \?, \+, \{, \|, \(, and \).

Comment: @Costas, that's GNU grep's man page. POSIX BRE spec are [there](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03). BRE equivalent of ERE `+` is `\{1,\}`. `[\n]` is not portable either. `\n\{1,\}` would be POSIX.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas OK, if you'd like to be so old-school you are welcome to change `\+` to `\{1,\}`

Comment: Also, you can't have another command after a label. `: 1;x` is to define the `1;x` label in POSIX seds. So you need: `sed -e :1 -e 'N;$!b1' -e 's/\n\{1,\}\( *[^0-9]\)/\1/g'`. Also note that many `sed` implementations have a small limit on the size of their pattern space (POSIX only guarantees 10 x LINE_MAX IIRC).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yes, I am worry about space limitation too, even try to play with `P` and `D` but I couldn't find acceptable solution

Answer (score 5):

One way would be:

```
 $ perl -lne 's/^/\n/ if $.>1 && /^\d+/; printf "%s",$_' file
 20141101 server contain dump
 20141101 server contain nothing    {uekdmsam ikdas jwdjamc ksadkek} ssfjddkc * kdlsdlsddsfd jfkdfk 
 20141101 server contain dump
```

However, .that also removes the final newline. To add it again, use:

```
$ { perl -lne 's/^/\n/ if $.>1 && /^\d+/; printf "%s",$_' file; echo; } > new
```

#### Explanation

The `-l` will remove trailing newlines (and also add one to each `print` call which is why I use `printf` instead. Then, if the current line starts with numbers (`/^\d+/`) and the current line number is greater than one (`$.>1`, this is needed to avoid adding an extra empty line at the beginning), add a `\n` to the beginning of the line. The `printf` prints each line.

---

Alternatively, you can change all `\n` characters to `\0`, then change those `\0` that are right before a string of numbers to `\n` again:

```
$ tr '\n' '\0' < file | perl -pe 's/\0\d+ |$/\n$&/g' | tr -d '\0'
20141101 server contain dump
20141101 server contain nothing    {uekdmsam ikdas jwdjamc ksadkek} ssfjddkc * kdlsdlsddsfd jfkdfk 
20141101 server contain dump
```

To make it match only strings of 8 numbers, use this instead:

```
$ tr '\n' '\0' < file | perl -pe 's/\0\d{8} |$/\n$&/g' | tr -d '\0'
```

Comment: The first argument to `printf` is the _format_. Use `printf "%s", $_`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas why? I mean, I know it's cleaner and perhaps easier to understand but is there any danger that that would protect from?

Comment: Yes, it's wrong and potentially dangerous if the input may contain % characters. Try with an input with `%10000000000s` for instance.

Comment: In C, that's a very well known very bad practice and vulnerability source. With `perl`, `echo %.10000000000f | perl -ne printf` brings my machine to its knees.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas wow, yes. Mine too. Fair enough then, answer edited and thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try doing this using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

{
    # if the current line begins with 8 digits followed by
    # 'nothing' OR the current line doesn't start with 8 digits
    if (/^[0-9]{8}.*nothing/ || !/^[0-9]{8}/) {
        # print current line without newline
        printf "%s", $0
        # feeding a 'state' variable
        weird=1
    }
    else {
        # if last line was treated in the 'if' statement
        if (weird==1) {
            printf "\n%s", $0
            weird=0
        }
        else {
            print # print the current line
        }
    }
}
END{
    print # add a newline when there's no more line to treat
}
```

To use it:

```
chmod +x script.awk
./script.awk file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Another simplest way (than my other answer) using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) and [terdon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22222/terdon)'s algorithm :

```
awk 'NR>1 && /^[0-9]{8}/{printf "%s","\n"$0;next}{printf "%s",$0}END{print}' file
```

Comment: ITYM `END{print ""}`. Alternative: `awk -v ORS= 'NR>1 && /^[0-9]{8}/{print "\n"};1;END{print "\n"}'`

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e:t -e '$!N;/\n *[0-9]{6}/!s/\n */ /;tt' -eP\;D
```

Answer (score 0):

Le programme en bash:

```bash
while read LINE
do
    if [[ $LINE =~ ^[0-9]{8} ]]
    then
        echo -ne "\n${LINE} "
    else
        echo -n "${LINE} "
    fi
done < file.txt
```

in one-line form:

```bash
while read L; do if [[ $L =~ ^[0-9]{8} ]]; then echo -ne "\n${L} "; else echo -n "${L} "; fi done < file.txt
```

Solution with backslashes preserving (`read -r`) and leading spaces (just `IFS=` after `while`):

```bash
while IFS= read -r LINE
do
    if [[ $LINE =~ ^[0-9]{8} ]]
    then
        echo
        echo -nE "\n${LINE} "
    else
        echo -nE "${LINE} "
    fi
done < file.txt
```

one-line form:

```bash
while IFS= read -r L; do if [[ $L =~ ^[0-9]{8} ]]; then echo; echo -nE "${L} "; else echo -nE "${L} "; fi done < file.text
```

Comment: This will break if the line contains, say, a backslash and an `n`. It also strips whitespace. But you can use `mksh` to do this: `while IFS= read -r L; do [[ $L = [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]* ]] && print; print -nr -- "$L"; done; print`

Comment: Of course it is not for everything algorithm, but solution for the requirements provided by the task. Of course the final solution will be more complex and less readable at a glance as it usually happens in Real Life :)

Comment: I agree, but I’ve learned the hard way to not assume too much about the OP ☺ especially if they replace the actual text by dummy text.

Answer (score 0):

```
[shyam@localhost ~]$ perl -lne 's/^/\n/ if $.>1 && /^\d+/; printf "%s",$_' appendDateText.txt
```

that will work

```
i/p:
##06/12/2016 20:30 Test Test Test
##TestTest
##06/12/2019 20:30 abbs  abcbcb abcbc
##06/11/2016 20:30 test test
##i123312331233123312331233123312331233123312331233Test
## 06/12/2016 20:30 abc

o/p:
##06/12/2016 20:30 Test Test TestTestTest
##06/12/2019 20:30 abbs  abcbcb abcbc
##06/11/2016 20:30 test ##testi123312331233123312331233123312331233123312331233Test
06/12/2016 20:30 abc vi appendDateText.txt
```